# How to set a value in a null JSON column with Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7.

I want to update a JSON column using Laravel's Eloquent. The problem is that if the value of the column is `null` the column won't be updated.

This is how the code looks like:

```php
Model::update(['jsonColumnName->jsonColumnKey' => 'value']);
```

This is the SQL that it would generate:

```sql
UPDATE model
SET jsonColumnName = JSON_SET(jsonColumnName, '$.jsonColumnKey', 'value');
```

According to the documentation of `JSON_SET`, it will take the first parameter as the JSON document that it will modify. In this case, that value would be `null` since `jsonColumnName` is currently `null`. Because of that it returns `null` since it has nothing to modify and it ends doing nothing.

If I manually set the value of the column to `{}` and run the showed code, it works. But I guess that you are not expected to do that (right?).

Comment: Why column is not `{}` by default in first place? How looks like migration for table?

Comment: @Tpojka The migration for the column would be `$table->json('jsonColumnName');`. About the "why" question I don't know, it's work's code.

Answer (score 0):

You should make new alter table migration and change json column to have default value `{}`.

First you need to check if there is already installed dbal with

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Then make new migration with code in `up()` method:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->json('column_name')->nullable()->default(null)->change();
});
```

Don't forget to backup database before work on it.

With NULL value you can also check if that field is empty.

Another way, on framework level is to set logic about this issue into model's [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers).

For example:

```
public function saving(EntityModel $entityModel)
{
    if (is_null($entityModel->json_column)) {
        $entityModel->json_column = '{}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that, if you are using MySQL (like me), you can only set a default value to a JSON column if you are using version 8.0.13 or later.

Comment: I know I can just update the value of the entries before running my "update" query but shouldn't the framework handle those cases?

Comment: With framework, you can set value for model property in model [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers). You can set [creating](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.html#method_creating) and [updating](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.html#method_updating) events.

Comment: Also, MySQL JSON column can have default `NULL` value. From docs: "A JSON column cannot have a non-NULL default value." So you can go with migration setting default null for column as I proposed in question's comment or go with code in observer where you would set value before saving/changing of model is made in database.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In your question's comment you say the column should be `{}` by default. But as said the DB version doesn't allow it. So right now is `null` by default. Is not specified in the migration, but it's the default behavior. The code observer suggestion you did is a good one I think, so if you could add ir as an answer I would mark it as accepted.